# Ключевое слово This и его применение в Классе\Пользовательской структуре

Tags: c#, .net, классы, структуры, keyword

Я заметил,что семантика работы ключевого слова "***this***" в пользовательских структурах и классах,кардинально отличается.
К примеру,в структуре мы можем сделать что то подобное :

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int x,y;

    void Reset()
    {
        this = new MyStruct(); // удаляем предыдущую структуру и создаем новую О_О
    }
}
```

Хотелось бы увидеть всю разницу ключевого слова ***This***, между структурой и классом,а так же узнать, что там твориться под капотом.

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038598/assign-this-keyword-in-c-sharp/10039022#10039022

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Самое главное различие состоит в том, что переменная `this` для структурного типа должна быть ***явно присвоенной*** в конструкторе структуры.

Переменная структурного типа, а `this`  для структур является переменной структурного типа, считается ***явно присвоенной*** , если каждое из ее полей является ***явно присвоенным***

Как это сказывается на структурах?

Это сказывается на работе конструкторов. Рассмотрите следующий пример объявления структуры

```
struct EvenOdd
{
    int x, y;
    void make_even()
    {
        x &= ~0 << 1;
    }

    void make_odd()
    {
        y |= 1;
    }

    public EvenOdd( int x, int y )
    {
        this.x = x;
        make_even();
        this.y = y;
        make_odd();
    }
}
```

Для этого объявления структуры компилятор выдаст сообщение об ошибке,

> Ошибка    CS0188  Невозможно использовать объект this, пока не будут
>   назначены все его поля.

потому что в точке вызова метода `make_even` `this` еще не является ***явно присвоенной***, так как член данных структуры `y` еще не был инициализирован.

После выхода из конструктора переменная `this` считается ***явно присвоенной***.

Вы можете сделать предыдущий конструктор структуры валидным посредством предварительного вызова конструктора по умолчанию

```
    public EvenOdd( int x, int y ) : this()
    {
        this.x = x;
        make_even();
        this.y = y;
        make_odd();
    }
```

В этом случае внутри тела конструктора с параметрами переменная `this` уже будет ***явно присвоенной***.

Если же вы измените это объявление на объявление класса, то никаких проблем с `this`, где `this` уже не переменная, а значение, не будет, и данный класс будет успешно компилироваться.

```
class EvenOdd
{
    int x, y;
    void make_even()
    {
        x &= ~0 << 1;
    }

    void make_odd()
    {
        y |= 1;
    }

    public EvenOdd( int x, int y )
    {
        this.x = x;
        make_even();
        this.y = y;
        make_odd();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Я думаю, лучше чем спецификация языка вам никто не ответит. (Кстати, спецификация находится на вашем компьютере, <Visual studio dir>\VC#\Specifications\1033\CSharp Language Specification.docx.)

Переведу раздел 7.6.7.

> Доступ через `this` разрешён лишь в теле нестатических конструктора, метода или акцессора [это геттер или сеттер — *VladD*]. Смысл `this` таков:
>
> - При использовании внутри нестатического конструктора класса `this` расценивается как *значение*. Тип этого значения есть тип [экземпляра] (см. §10.3.1) класса, в котором происходит использование, и значение есть ссылка на конструируемый объект.
> - При использовании внутри нестатического метода или акцессора `this` расценивается как *значение*. Тип этого значения есть тип [экземпляра] (см. §10.3.1) класса, в котором происходит использование, и значение есть ссылка на объект, у которого был вызван метод или акцессор.
> - При использовании внутри нестатического конструктора структуры `this` расценивается как *переменная*. Тип этой переменной есть тип [экземпляра] (см. §10.3.1) структуры, в которой происходит использование, и значение представляет конструируемую структуру. Переменная `this` в конструкторе [экземпляра] структуры ведёт себя в точности как `out`-параметр того же типа; в частности, это означает, что переменная должна быть гарантировано инициализирована на любом пути выполнения конструктора.
> - При использовании внутри нестатического метода или акцессора `this` расценивается как *переменная*. Тип этой переменной есть тип [экземпляра] (см. §10.3.1) структуры, в которой происходит использование.
>
>   - Если метод или акцессор не является итератором (см. §10.14), переменная `this` представляет структуру, для которой метод или акцессор был вызван, и ведёт себя в точности как `ref`-параметр данного типа.
>   - Если метод или акцессор является итератором, переменная `this` представляет *копию* структуры, для которой метод или акцессор был вызван, и ведёт себя в точности как параметр этого же типа, переданный по значению.

(Я немного упростил текст, убрав упоминание *primary-expression*.)

---

Видно, что для классов `this` представляет собой значение, а для структур — переменную. Поэтому для структур можно осуществлять присвоение этой переменной.